# why this happening<django.db.models.query_utils.DeferredAttribute object at 0x00000256CA7C05E0>

Tags: django, django-views, django-database

## views.py

getting something else 
in output instead of values present in it
I am trying but not gating answers
please provide me some suggestions
I think so error occurs in :(instance=Task)

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import *
from  MYapp.models import *
from .form import *

def venue(request):
  venue_list = Task.objects.all()

  return render(request,'MYapp/venue.html',{'venue_list': venue_list})

def navebar(request):

  return render(request,'MYapp/navebar.html')


def db(request,db_id):
  venues = Task.objects.get(pk=db_id)
  return render(request,'MYapp/db.html',{'venues': venues})

def search(request):
  if request.method =="POST":
      searched = request.POST.get('searched', False)
      Tasks =Task.objects.filter( firstname__contains = searched)
      return render(request,'MYapp/search.html',{'searched':searched, 'Tasks':Tasks})    
  else:
      return render(request,'MYapp/search.html',{})    

def update(request,db_id):
  venues = Task.objects.get(pk=db_id)
  form = TaskForm(request.POST or None, instance=Task)
  return render(request,'MYapp/update.html',{'venues': venues,'form':form})
```

Comment: Please try to write a more clear question. And use punctuation.

Comment: sorry this is my first time I will pay attention to words it

Answer (score 0):

assigning a variable instead of class

```
 def update(request,db_id):
    venues = Task.objects.get(pk=db_id)
    form = TaskForm(request.POST or None, instance=Task)
    return render(request,'MYapp/update.html',{'venues': 
    venues,'form':form})
```

do this

```
 def update(request,db_id):
    venues = Task.objects.get(pk=db_id)
    form = TaskForm(request.POST or None, instance=venues )
    return render(request,'MYapp/update.html',{'venues': 
    venues,'form':form})
```